# jhipster spring boot tomcat java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jhipster

we currently have a problem with our jhipster application. from time to time the following exception is logged on our server

```
2021-12-15 09:58:09.813 ERROR 2784 --- [0.1-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:360)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:873)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:591)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:176)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:245)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

we use the following technologies:

- jhipster 5.8.2. with embedded tomcat
- spring boot 2.0.8.
- angular 7.3.1.

i can't exactly tell what causes the exception mentioned above to be thrown and furthermore we do not see any impact on the functionality of the program itself but the exception causes our logfile to get spammed with these exceptions.

additionally, the exception is only logged when we deploy the app to our ubuntu server but the exception does not get logged when i run/debug the app locally in my eclipse IDE on my windows pc.

furthermore, locally on my windows pc i run the app with oracle jdk 8 and on the ubuntu server we run the app with openjdk 11. could this make a difference?

additional note:
we switched from spring-boot-starter-undertow to spring-boot-starter-tomcat recently and since then the exception is thrown permanently (it was never thrown using spring-boot-starter-undertow)

any help how to get rid of this exception would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 17.12.2021:**
i forgot to mention that we are **heavily** relying on websockets for our angular clients to receive updates from the spring boot server in realtime

after observing the problem for a while we noticed that often (nearly always) before the exception is thrown the following warnings are logged:

```
2021-12-17 10:31:25.352  WARN 18686 --- [0.1-8080-exec-5] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTrait    : Forbidden: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.
2021-12-17 10:31:28.496  WARN 18686 --- [.1-8080-exec-10] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTrait    : Forbidden: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.
2021-12-17 10:31:28.897  WARN 18686 --- [0.1-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService       : Origin check enabled but transport 'jsonp' does not support it.
```

these warnings also occured when we used undertow but the IllegalStateExceptions did not get thrown.

additionally, after the first exception mentioned above is thrown it's always followed by the following exception, which i assume is a consequence of the first exception (embedded tomcat seems to try to redirect to a tomcat error page due to the first thrown exception as seen in cause)

```
2021-12-17 10:18:43.535 ERROR 18686 --- [0.1-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:989)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:873)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:591)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:230)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:245)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:360)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

is it possible, that the warnings mentioned above cause these IllegalStateExceptions to be thrown but only with embedded tomcat but not with embedded undertow? is there anything configured for embedded undertow to not throw these exceptions?

if these warnings were the reason for these exceptions, how could we get rid of these warnings and hence the exceptions?

Comment: Not really related to JHipster as you're not using Undertow. JHipster does not uses Thymeleaf for views (seen in your stacktrace) unless for errors, so unless your app does use Thymeleaf I would look for an error and maybe run remote debugging. Of course, your dev environment shoumld be as similar as possible to your production environment: same jdk and same OS if possible, so you should start by same JDK. Regarding JDK 11, you use Spring Boot 2.0, support for JDK 11 was added in 2.1

Comment: @GaëlMarziou you are absolutely right regarding the fact that the dev environment should be as similar to the prod environment as possible. we already switched to jdk8 on our ubuntu server (it's also a miracle to us that it has been working with jdk11 for over a year now) but the exceptions are still thrown. i updated the original question with some more information, maybe it helps to find a way to solve the problem?

Comment: Well you should try the usual tools: increase logging level, remote debug or try to reproduce in dev. If all fails, switch back to Undertow or ignore these errors because so far you did not say what their impact was.